# Problems running Apache and PHP with the mcrypt and mhash extensions

Tags: windows-7, apache2, mcrypt, php-5.5, mhash

Here's my problem:
I'm trying to install PHP and Apache on a 64-bit windows environment. I started out with 64-bit Apache 2.4.10 and 64-bit PHP 5.5.20. Everything installed great and then I found out I needed to use the mcrypt and mhash extensions. I could only find these extensions on SourceForge, and it looks like they're only available in 32 bit. So, I reinstalled Apache 32-bit and PHP 32-bit. But then I encountered a problem that the PHP5apache module wouldn't work because it's a 64-bit module apparently. Is there a solution which will allow me to run Apache and PHP with these modules together on Windows?

Thanks for reading and I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the mcrypt extension comes already as of PHP 5.3. And  mhash for me is no longer relevant so I'm considering this question answered.